# Threading a variable number of heterogeneous input files, process the input and output to a single file

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I am trying improve the performance of the job listed below.  As is, without threading, it runs successfully.  But is runs very slow.  I would like to thread step 2 where 95% of the work happens in the reading, filtering and transforming the input data read from very large heterogeneous files.  The job:

•   Step1 gets some job parameters that are passed into Step2.

•   Step2 will read in X number of files.  Each file is heterogenous, i.e., contains several different record formats.  The records are filtered, transformed and sent to a single output file.

Does Spring Batch have a built-in way to thread Step2 in this scenario?  For example, can I add some type of executor to step2?  I’ve tried SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.  Neither work.  Adding SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor throws an exception. (See [can we process the multiple files sequentially using spring Batch while multiple threads used to process individual files data..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883344/can-we-process-the-multiple-files-sequentially-using-spring-batch-while-multiple.))

Here is the batch configuration:

```
                public Job job() {
                                return jobBuilderFactory.get("MyJob")
                                                                .start(step1())
                                                                .next(step2())
                                                                .build();
                }              

                @Bean
                public Step step1()  {
                                return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step1GetJobParams")
                                                                .tasklet(MyParamsTasklet)
                                                                .build();
                }
                
                @Bean
                public Step step2() {
                                return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step2")
                                                                .<InputDO, OutputDO>chunk(1000)
                                                                .reader(myMultiResourceReader())
                                                                .processor(myStep2ItemProcessor)
                                                                .writer(myStep2FileWriter())
                                                                .taskExecutor(???)                                          line #23
                            .build();
                }
                
                @Bean
                public MultiResourceItemReader<InputDO> myMultiResourceReader(){
                                MultiResourceItemReader<InputDO> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<InputDO>();
                                multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resourceManager.getResources());
                                multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(myStep2FileReader());
                                multiResourceItemReader.setSaveState(false);
                                return multiResourceItemReader;
                }
                
                @Bean
                public FlatFileItemReader<InputDO> myStep2FileReader() {
                                return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<InputDO>()
                                                               .name("MyStep2FileReader")
                                                               .lineMapper(myCompositeLineMapper())
                                                               .build();
                }
                
                @Bean 
                 public PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<InputDO> myCompositeLineMapper() {
                                PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<InputDO> lineMapper = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<InputDO>();
                                Map<String, LineTokenizer> tokenizers = new HashMap<String, LineTokenizer>();
                                tokenizers.put("A", InputDOTokenizer.getInputDOTokenizer());
                                tokenizers.put("*", InputDOFillerTokenizer.getInputDOFillerTokenizer());
                                lineMapper.setTokenizers(tokenizers);
                                Map<String, FieldSetMapper<InputDO>> mappers = new HashMap<String, FieldSetMapper<InputDO>>();
                                mappers.put("A", new InputDOFieldSetMapper());
                                mappers.put("*", new InputDOFillerFieldSetMapper());
                                lineMapper.setFieldSetMappers(mappers);
                                return lineMapper; 
                 }
                
                @Bean
                public FlatFileItemWriter<OutputDO> myOutputDOFileWriter() {
                                return  new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<OutputDO>()
                                               .name("MyOutputDOFileWriter")
                                               .resource(resourceManager.getFileSystemResource("myOutputDOFileName"))
                                               .lineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<OutputDO>() {
                                                               {
                                                                                                setDelimiter("");
                                                                                                setFieldExtractor(outputDOFieldExtractor.getOutputDOFieldExtractor());
                                                                                };
                                               })
                                               .lineSeparator("\r\n")
                                               .build();
                }
```

Any/all guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you reduce the size of your question?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use this mode of Multi-threaded Step to resolve read slowly problem. more details is available from [spring batch office - Multi-threaded Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) about it.

Hope to help you.